# Set ELM327 to listen

Tags: network-protocols, elm327

I'm wondering if there is a way to set ELM327 to listen on the bus. Apparently the ELM only listens when a command is been sent to wait for the response, but what I want is to display all the received frames instead of just the response

Comment: In the ELM327 datasheet there is a chapter called _Monitoring the Bus_. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is more a hardware question that should be asked on the electronics or microcontroller stackexchanges.

Answer (score 1):

`ATMA` is the command you want to use. Be warned though, the ELM327 has a very tiny buffer so you will be presented with a `Buffer full` error after just a few frames.

If you seriously want to listen to the bus, you either need to use a STN11xx or STN22xx derived OBD2 adapter, or – if it's a CAN bus – a CAN2USB adapter.

Comment: can you recommend any wireless CAN2USB adapters?